# Fetch table query in Oracle database for data extraction?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want Oracle SQL Developer to create a SELECT statement "automatically" for the table that are in databse, I want the table query for extraction and so that I do not have to type for all.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Excuse me, but ... what do you want?

Comment: You have tagged both Oracle and SQL Server - 2 completely different database products, do you require a solution for both?

Comment: Like `SELECT *
FROM all_tables`?

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess: you want SQL Developer to create a SELECT statement "automatically". If so, then drag table into the editor and choose an option:

[image]

Result:

```
SELECT
    ename,
    job,
    sal,
    comm
FROM
    bonus;
```

Comment: in oracle, can not drag and drop. any other way?

Comment: My screenshot **is Oracle**, so - you're doing something wrong.

Comment: it doesn't get me options prompt like you, it just gives me column data no matter what.